# User expirity resets after rule fires

Tags: 7, users, rules

I have a rule, that sets user expiration date from a date field (this is on the same user account, I need this for another rule). However, after the rule fires the user expiration date is beeing reset (in case no other data was set there, otherwise it gets back to the previously set date).
That means the rule works but it is useless, while something is overwrinting it.
the question is, why does user expiration resets.

The rule exported:

```
{ "rules_set_user_exp" : {
    "LABEL" : "set user exp",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "user_expire" ],
    "ON" : { "user_update" : [] },
    "IF" : [ { "NOT data_is_empty" : { "data" : [ "account:field-exp-date" ] } } ],
    "DO" : [
      { "user_expire" : { "account" : [ "account" ], "expiration" : [ "account:field-exp-date" ] } }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Please include an export of the rule you have. Also: what is your actual question?

Comment: after deactivating and reactiveateing the module i have still no idea why user expiration date has been reset again. also i tried to set up a page on localhost, with less settings and modules to find if it is a problem with my settings, but still the same error.